# When quotient of a $k$-algebra by any maximal ideal is $k$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

Let $k$ be a valued field.
Is there a special term for a commutative (Banach) $k$-algebra $A$ such that for any maximal ideal $m$ we have $A/m=k$?
Is there an easy to check criterion that would imply this property?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Actually, I think it's difficult to understand it as it is currently phrased.

Comment: To give an example for the 2nd question: In case $k = \mathbb R$, the Banach algebra $E := C_b(X)$ of bounded continuous real-valued functions over a completely regular space X has this property. If $m$ is a max. ideal, then one defines a total ordering on $E/m$ that extends the order of $\mathbb R \le E/m$ and has no infinitely large elements (that's because the functions are bounded). Now a general theorem on ordered fields implies $E/m = \mathbb R$. 

Comment: @Fernando: Please tell me which part of the question is unclear or needs more explanation and I will edit it. 
\\
@Ralph: Another example is the algebra of continuous functions on a compact space. So, the actual question is a bit broad - how one can check (algebraically) if an algebra is the algebra of continuous k-valued functions on some "good" space?

Comment: One way to construct such an algebra is to start with any algebra and then invert every $x$ in the algebra and every polynomial $f$ with no roots in $k$, invert $f(x)$. It is easy to see that this kills all the non-$k$ points and keeps all the $k$-points. I don't think there is any reasonable classification of such spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is a standard term for what you are looking for, but I would be inclined to call such an algebra "compact".  My reason is the following.  Suppose that $X$ is a manifold (resp. locally compact Hausdorff space).  Then the maximal spectrum of the ring $C^\infty(X)$ of smooth real-valued functions (resp. $C^0(X)$ of continuous real-valued functions) with the Zariski topology is homeomorphic to the Stone--Cech compactification $\beta X$ of $X$.  If $X$ is not astronomically large*, then the points $\mathfrak m \in \beta X$ for which the quotient field $C^\infty(X)/\mathfrak m$ (resp. $C^0(X)/\mathfrak m$) is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ are precisely the points in $X \hookrightarrow \beta X$.  In particular, $X$ is compact iff $\beta X = X$ iff every maximal ideal comes from a point of $X$ iff every maximal ideal has quotient field $\mathbb R$.

I said this over $\mathbb R$, but really any infinite field $\mathbb K$ will do.  (Then I need to take "isomorphic" to mean "isomorphic as $\mathbb K$-algebras", so that if something is isomorphic to $\mathbb K$, then it is so uniquely.  Over $\mathbb R$, I can in fact take "isomorphic" to mean "isomorphic as rings", since $\mathbb R$ has no nontrivial ring automorphisms.)

*Footnote: The claim fails if there is a measurable cardinal $\lambda > |\mathbb K|$ with $|X| \geq \lambda$.  Note that in many universes there are no uncountable measurable cardinals at all, and if uncountable measurable cardinals exist, then they are strongly inaccessible, and hence very very large.